# Why does this model test pass on CentOS, but fail on Mac OS X (Lion)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rspec2

This spec passes just fine on my CentOS development box, but fails when run on my Macbook (10.7).

app/models/issue.rb

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :cover_image,
    :styles => {
      :thumbnail => ["80x80>"],
      :large => ["600x600>"]
    },
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/issues/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
    :url => "issues/:id/:style_:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :cover_image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
  attr_protected :cover_image_file_name, :cover_image_content_type, :cover_image_file_size
end
```

spec/models/issue_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Issue do
  it 'should not accept invalid image types' do
    %w[spec/factories/assets/docs/image.jpg spec/factories/assets/docs/image.txt].each do |file_path| #image.jpg is a text file with a .jpg extension
      issue = Factory.build(:issue, :cover_image => File.new(Rails.root + file_path))
      issue.should have(2).errors_on(:cover_image)
    end
  end
end
```

On my CentOS development box, I get no failures when I run the test. On my Macbook I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: issue.should have(2)errors_on(:cover_image)
  expected 2 errors on :cover_image, got 0
```

On both machines if I try to create an issue by uploading one of the invalid image types in a browser, it fails with the error message I expect and passes if I use a valid image type.

```
paperclip-2.4.2
rspec-2.6.0
factory_girl_rails-1.2.0

CentOS: ImageMagick-6.2.8 (yum package)
Mac OS X: ImageMagick-6.7.2-0 (Macports)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my whole approach to testing paperclip was off.

[Paperclip Shoulda Matchers](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Shoulda/Matchers) are working on both machines.